# Django: accessing session variable while overriding model's save method

Tags: django, django-models

Is there any way to access sessions variables while overriding any models save method

```
class Blog(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  tagline = models.TextField()

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    //Code for accessing session variable
    super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not directly

you **could** add an extra argument to the save method and pop it off before calling the super save:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop('request')

view...:
    instance.save(request=request)
```

**But**
if you are saving a form it may be better to use

```
view...:
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    # do some logic
    instance.save()
```